# How to use migration programmatically in EntityFramework Codefirst?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working in a project that uses EF Code First. I'm trying to use migration features. I don't want to use Package Console Manager. How can I execute the "Add-Migration" and "Update-Database" programmatically?

```
add-migration TestMigration01 -force

update-database
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a couple of choices. You can use the dbmigrator class from within your code: http://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/

Or you can use migrate.exe which is handy for running them in a build step, etc.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx