# Entity Framework apply migrations at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

i'm creating a C# WinForms application which uses Entity Framework Code First and it is set to create the database if it doesn't exists.

Since the app is not distributed with a database, it creates it when it's needed, so i need to find a way to detect which migrations need to be applied for each case when i release a new version of the app.

How can i detect and apply needed migrations at runtime?

Comment: have you checked [this SO QA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144784/how-to-use-migration-programmatically-in-entityframework-codefirst) especially [this link that uses DB Migrator](https://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/). It still available in [EF 6](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Migrations/DbMigrator.cs) so, it might relevant to your question..

Comment: This seems to be exactly what i was looking for, Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this Initializer:System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion,it will update your database（no delete db,no delete data）,just update entity changed.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<T, DbMigrationsConfiguration<T>>());
        try
        {
            using (var ctx = new T())
            {
                ctx.Database.Initialize(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: I used a variation of what you proposed.

`Database.SetInitializer<ObjectContext>(
    new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ObjectContext, Configuration>());`

Comment: Just a very slight nitpick.. empty catch blocks are no end of trouble...

Comment: @gburton it's actually just the beginning of another one.