# Use Entity Framework Code-First Migration to update DB schema when application start

Tags: entity-framework, migration, database-schema, code-first

I am developing window application in which DB schema can be different between each release (update view, add/remove column). Therefore I am looking for way to let EF update schema when application start up in client machine. I read some article but they point to package manager command `Add-Migration, Update-Database` which I can not use in my case.
I used repository pattern so when I tried `Database.SetInitializer<C>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<C, Configuration<C>>());`
I got **Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.** exception
But when I set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;`I got another error: **Table 'TableName' already exists.**

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144784/how-to-use-migration-programmatically-in-entityframework-codefirst) and [here](https://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/)

Comment: I already read and tried above but no success, I updated my question to have more detail @SteveGreene

Comment: Sounds like you don't have migrations properly configured. You need to make an initial baseline migration `Add-Migration MyBaseline -IgnoreChanges`. Then you add migrations as normal for subsequent changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, create an extension method

```
    public static void RunMigration(this DbContext context, DbMigration migration)
    {
        var prop = migration.GetType().GetProperty("Operations", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (prop != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> operations = prop.GetValue(migration) as IEnumerable<MigrationOperation>;
            var generator = new SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator();
            var statements = generator.Generate(operations, "2008");
            foreach (MigrationStatement item in statements)
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(item.Sql);
        }
    }
```

And then create class `MyMigration` which inherit DbMigration like normal migration, and when application start, I will check and force it to run like below:

```
var myMigration = new MyMigration();
myMigration.Up();
this.RunMigration(myMigration);
```