# Can I add migration from C# code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

I wonder if it is possible to prepare equivalent to `Add-Migration` from C# code. I found how to update and yet preparing migration is still a blocker.

Main problem is that addding from PM console fails caused by the fact that GC removed some object related to remoting. Retrying action works but it is insufficient.

Anything like extending system timeout or leasetime didn't work.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use migration programmatically in EntityFramework Codefirst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144784/how-to-use-migration-programmatically-in-entityframework-codefirst)

Comment: @FakeCaleb Been there and no solution for the `Add-Migration` part. Only update.